# How To Replace Wordpress Native Player With Fluid Player?

Tags: video-player

I Want To Replace My Wordpress Native Video Player (Default Video Player) With Fluid player because i want to Display VAST Advertising on my videos. So How To Replace Wordpress Native Video Player With Fluid Player ?

I uses a plugin which creates video posts and all videos are being played in native video player. It will be very big update if wordpress update it's native video player with VAST Advertising technology...